# loadUrl twice in Android webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to load 2 URL's in a webview, one after the other, and grab their html. My code looks as following:

```
final WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.showInfo_webView);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
        }
    });

    webview.loadUrl(response);
    webview.loadUrl(response2); <--

class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showHTML(String html) {
    ...
    }
}
```

In `showHTML` I'd have a counter so I can distinguish between the first and the second call. However, `showHTML` gets called only once. Why is that? Do I need to recreate the webview entirely?

I tried calling `webview.reload()` after the 2nd `loadUrl` but then it looks like  the 2nd page is loaded twice?

EDIT: I need to process the 1st URL html to obtain the 2nd URL.

Comment: @MikeM. You mean doing HTTP post/get? Doesn't work since I'm dealing with dynamic web pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around it by creating an activity which basically only has the webview. I `startActivityForResult` twice in a row and that's it. It's certainly not elegant but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
     String[] urls =  {"http://www.demo.com", "http://www.fb.com"};

            int delay = 50 * 1000;
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            for(int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {

                webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                MyRunnable runnable = new MyRunnable(urls[i], webview);
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
                delay = delay + 50 * 1000;
            }

private class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        private String url;
        private WebView wv;

        public MyRunnable(String url, WebView wv) {
            this.url = url;
            this.wv = wv;
        }

        public void run() {
           webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
        }
    });
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem I see with this is that I need to process the html from the 1st url before calling the 2nd, which would only work here assuming it's done during the pre-set delay